# Convex conjugate of $\vert\cdot\vert^2+\vert\cdot\vert^p$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a question concerning the convex conjugate of $f:=\vert\cdot\vert^2+\vert\cdot\vert^p$ where $\vert\cdot\vert$ is the euclidean norm and $p>2$. More precisely, I am wondering if the following two sides inequality holds true : for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ ($d\geq  2$)
$$c(\vert x\vert^2+\vert x\vert^{p'})\leq f^*(x)\leq C(\vert x\vert^2+\vert x\vert^{p'}),$$
for some constants $c,C>0$ and where $f^*$ denotes the convex conjugate of $f$ and $p'$ the conjugate exponent of $p$. Does anyone have a proof/counter exemple ? Thanks !